# does Ajax controls works if the allowjavascript option turned off in browser

Tags: ajax.net

If user turned off the javascript in the browser ,does the Ajax controls work?

If it works how is it possible since ajax is using javascript.

Thanks
SC

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: **No**. It does not work and you have no chance of getting AJAX to work when the client has disabled his javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax controls will not work unless javascript is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX - still means, Asynchronous JAVASCRIPT and XML. 
So, if the browser has turned off the J, then no, it won't work.

Comment: Then how can i use ajax controls trusting on client browsers? Is this a major drawback ?how do you evaluate?